# Is SHA256 considered insecure?- SonarQube Quality Gate - How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, sonarqube, md5

I have below piece of code

```
        private static string sensitiveKey = "<REPLACE_WITH_KEY>"  

        public static string Encrypt(string input)
        {
            // Get the bytes of the string
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sensitiveKey);
            // Hash the password with SHA256
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
            byte[] bytesEncrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(input, passwordBytes);
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
            return result;
        }
```

SonarQube says

> Cryptographic hash functions are used to uniquely identify information without storing their original form. When not done properly, an attacker can steal the original information by guessing it (ex: with a rainbow table), or replace the original data with another one having the same hash.

Also

> use only hashing algorithms which are currently known to be strong. Avoid using algorithms like **MD5** and **SHA1** completely in security contexts.

So question is, How can I improve my code so that it can be secure?

Any samples out thr?

Comment: That code does not use MD5 nor SHA1.

Comment: As Fildor pointed out, your code doesn't use MD5, instead it uses SHA256. Which isn't really better than MD5 as [general-purpose hashes are obsolete for passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/90064/202963). Instead you should use a function which is specifically made for password hashing like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2)

Comment: updated title of the question.   let me try using bcrypt or Argon2 . some samples would be appreciated.

Comment: @Fildor   do u recommend any other code scanner rather than sonarqube?

Comment: I don't recommend anything. Haven't done research into codescanners for years.

Comment: "When not done properly, an attacker can steal the original information by guessing it (ex: with a rainbow table), **or replace the original data with another one having the same hash.**" that last part is only true for broken hash functions like MD5, just applying a known good hash "incorrectly" is not going to get you there. Actually, the whole SonarQube description is below par. But yeah, use a password hash for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a salt to the hashed password since unsalted hashes tend to be more vulnerable to dictionary and rainbow table attacks.

```
hash("hello") =
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824

hash("hello" + "QxLUF1bgIAdeQX") = 
9e209040c863f84a31e719795b2577523954739fe5ed3b58a75cff2127075ed1

hash("hello" + "bv5PehSMfV11Cd") = 
d1d3ec2e6f20fd420d50e2642992841d8338a314b8ea157c9e18477aaef226ab
```

The code above is an example of how salting usually works. You concatenate a fixed string to the password and then hash the result. The salt should be of fixed length and should **never be reused**. This is how it could look like in your case:

```
        private static string salt = "<REPLACE_WITH_FIXED_LENGTH_SALT>";
        private static string sensitiveKey = "<REPLACE_WITH_KEY>";  
        private static string salted_key = salt + sensitiveKey;

        public static string Encrypt(string input)
        {
            // Get the bytes of the string
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salted_key);
            // Hash the password with SHA256
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
            byte[] bytesEncrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(input, passwordBytes);
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
            return result;
        }
```